# Mongodb Sorting by value

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

This is my collection TOPIC

```
{
 "_id" : "topic_1",
 "createdBy" : "user1",
 "bookmarkers_color" : [ 
    {
        "account_id" : "user1",
        "color" : "rgb(255, 152, 0)"
    }
 ]
},

{
 "_id" : "topic_2",
 "createdBy" : "user2",
 "bookmarkers_color" : [ 
    {
        "account_id" : "user2",
        "color" : "rgb(255, 152, 0)"
    }
 ]
},

{
 "_id" : "topic_3",
 "createdBy" : "user2",
 "bookmarkers_color" : [ 
    {
        "account_id" : "user1",
        "color" : "rgb(255, 152, 0)"
    },
    {
        "account_id" : "user2",
        "color" : "rgb(255, 152, 0)"
    }
 ]
}
```

I have to just sort the collection by `bookmarkers_color.account_id` where account_id is `user1`. And want the whole TOPIC collection in return. In this scenario, my expected output should be like this that the `topic_2` should come in last.

Answer (score 0):

Just do normal [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#ascending-descending-sort):

```
db.topic.find().sort({'bookmarkers_color.account_id':1});
```

With ascending sorting, it sorts documents by min value of array elements, so first you get documents where `account_id:"user1"` exists in the `bookmarkers_color` array, then documents with `account_id:"user2"` etc.

Comment: actually these account_ids (user1, user2) are just dummy. I hope that you are aware with the random account_ids

Comment: @MohammadKashifSulaiman I'd suggest you to do some research yourself before posting question. There are very good resources available all over internet.

Comment: @MohammadKashifSulaiman How could I be aware about your random account_ids if it is not in the question? Update the question with examples of data where proposed solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.topic.find({}).sort({"bookmarkers_color.account_id":1})
```

this should solve your problem.